# How to check application HTML page on iPad?

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there any tool where we check our code online in iPad or tablet online?

I found one link, it is [only for iphone](http://play.ionic.io/app/57fcf12a030b). Does anybody know same type of link where we check our code for iPad or tablets?

Comment: SO is not the right forum for this question I believe

Comment: where to ask could you please tell me

Comment: If you are looking for 'simple' reviewing the layout in a format like a tablet of phone, use firefox' Webdeveloper Responsive Design View.

Comment: ok but is there any tool as I given above link .so show preview right screen

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Google's Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/) and if you open up the [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) you will see a nice device emulation option, and you can choose from a lot of predefined devices or enter your own resolution:

[image]